# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have python function:

**FactorialFunction.py**

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
        f = n * factorial(n-1)
    print(f)
    return(f)
    factorial(4)
```

shows nothing, when I run it in terminal

[image]

but when I run it in python shell get **"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment"**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to follow the python code indentation.

```
if n == 0:
    return 1
    f = n * factorial(n-1)
```

`f = n * factorial(n-1)` this statement never reached with python code. because it will `return` before reach this statement.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    f = n * factorial(n-1)
    print(f)
    return(f)
factorial(4)
```